# How to redirect to another server in mvc using post method?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I want to redirect on another domain server from controller.

Also I have to get a response from the server.

How to achieve this in ASP.NET MVC?

We have not implemented a Model section. I found a solution for web forms.

Comment: Can't you do a `HttpClient` POST from C# code and get the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    You can use the HttpWebRequest class to make the post to the other server and then redirect as normal

    //code would be something like this
    var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http:your url");
    httpRequest.Method = "POST";
    httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    string data = "key=value&key2=value2";
    byte[] dataArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
    httpRequest.ContentLength = dataArray.Length;

    //actual code to call another server
     using(Stream requestStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        requestStream.Write(dataArray, 0, dataArray.Length);
        var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
    }
```